# jquery ajax fileupload

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need an asynchronous file uploader. No, i am not looking for a plugin. I am just looking for a simple jquery+AJAX uploader that will upload the file asynchronously. I have checked Google but haven't found anything useful.

Here is my html:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" "> 

File Name:<input type="text" name="name"/> <br/><br/>

Browse: <input type="file" name="file"/> <br/><br/> 

<input type="submit" id='button' Value="Upload the video file" name="submit"/>

 </form>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$filename=$_POST["name"];
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$size=$size/1000000;
$size=round($size, 2);
$size.="MB";
$namewithext=$filename." (".$size.")".".".$ext;
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    if (file_exists("file/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo "<script> alert('".$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. "."');</script>";
      }
    else
      {

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "file/" . $namewithext);
      echo "<script> alert('"."success"."');</script>";


      }
    }
}
  else
  {

  }
?>
```

I have no experience with jquery. Thanks so much!

Comment: _"No, i am not looking for a plugin. I am just looking for a simple jquery+AJAX uploader that will upload the file asynchronously."_ so you're looking for a plugin...

Comment: Also, I don't see a real question here. It's more like "Here's what I want. Write code for me." Maybe if you had a problem or an error with something you're trying we could help.

Comment: is it not possible with just simple coding? because i am not looking for a progressbar or some other fancy stuff. I just want an uploader that will upload the file when "submit" is clicked, without posting back the page. Thanks!

Comment: my question is what is the jquery code that will send the file to the server

Comment: I don't believe there is such a function in jQuery that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inevitable that you will have to use a "plugin" to your definition, but...

**Here's the good news:**

There's a really good, easy to use, simple to code jQuery-File-Upload by blueimp that you can [Download Here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#download).

**You wanted it simple:**

Since you are looking for it to be a simple, basic jQuery... You can [Look Here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) for a basic tutorial on what you're looking for.

**Side note:**

It isn't so much a site plug-in as a javascript library to do what you want to for a "Basic File jQuery uploader.

**Other option:**

Your only other option without uploading javascript libraries would be to use an iFrame that you post the uploaded iFrame to, which can simulate jQuery, in the way that you don't have to reload the page for it to upload the file.